# How to include special characters on Monit (monitrc) config file?

Tags: monit

OS: CentOS 7.4
     Monit: 5.14
     WebServer: Nginx 1.12.2

How could I insert special characters (specifically '@')  on the config file (/etc/monit.d/monitrc)?

I am trying to do the following:

#Monitor clamd@amavisd service

```
  check process clamd@amavisd with pidfile /var/run/amavisd/amavisd.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/systemctl start clamd@amavisd"
  stop  program = "/usr/bin/systemctl stop clamd@amavisd"
  if cpu usage > 99% for 5 cycles then alert
  if mem usage > 99% for 5 cycles then alert
```

But monit -t issues an error for '@' character. I've tried:

1. '@' and 'clamd@amavisd'
2. "@" and "clamd@amavisd"
3. \@

For other services such as amavisd below, it runs like a charm:

# Monitor Amavis-new service

```
  check process amavisd with pidfile /var/run/amavisd/amavisd.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/systemctl start amavisd"
  stop  program = "/usr/bin/systemctl stop amavisd"
  if cpu usage > 99% for 5 cycles then alert
  if mem usage > 99% for 5 cycles then alert
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#TCP-PORT):

> You might need to use double quotes around the password if it contains special chars such as `"p@ssw:r#"`.